# Flutter: using library universal_io/io.dart when others libs based on dart:io

Tags: flutter, dart, import, dart-io

I want port my app to webapp, but I can't run my app as webapp. Why? Because another libs based on dart:io, not universal_io.

Terminal output:

```
lib/services/my_local_storage.dart:134:36: Error: The argument type 'File/*1*/' can't be assigned to
the parameter type 'File/*2*/'.
 - 'File/*1*/' is from 'package:universal_io/src/io/file.dart'
 ('/C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/universal_io-2.0.4/lib/src/io/fi
 le.dart').
 - 'File/*2*/' is from 'dart:io'.
        VideoPlayerController.file(File(myCacheDir!.path + "/" + path));
```

For example:

```dart
VideoPlayerController _controller =
        VideoPlayerController.file(File(myCacheDir!.path + "/" + path));
```

class VideoPlayerController need `File` as parameter, but inside video_player I see `import dart:io`. Moreover I have some others libs based on dart:io. How to solve it?

Comment: You would need to replace these libs with other versions that works. You could also download the libs yourself, fix them and point to them as dependencies (you can point to a directory as dependency). Alternative, you can try make an issue on the problematic projects and ask them to make a fix. Or you can help the project and make a pull request with a fix.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution or a replacement?